# Using a list to print elements of a double list

Tags: python-3.x

Hi there I am new to python and I am working on double lists and lists. I have this double list:

```
 doubleList = [['123', 'user1', 'its.zip', 1495212715.6226974],
 ['123', 'user1', 'New Compressed (zipped) Folder.zip', 1495638517.22533], 
 ['123', 'user1', 'zippedtto.zip', 1495212754.2919347], 
 ['123', 'user2', 'Iam.zip', 1495212805.4040027], 
 ['acd', 'Letsee.zip', 1495478626.503554]]
```

and this single list:

```
ListNum = [1495638517.212533, 1495212805.4040027, 1495478626.503554]
```

I want to change my double list so that it contains elements whose last value is the number in ListNum.

In this case my output would be:

```
output = 
[['123', 'user1', 'New Compressed (zipped) Folder.zip',1495638517.22533],
 ['123', 'user2', 'Iam.zip', 1495212805.4040027],
['acd', 'Letsee.zip', 1495478626.503554]]
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Are you assuming that 1495638517.22533 is equal to 1495638517.212533?, is the only way I  can think of your example works, is that a typo?

Comment: My bad. It's a typo. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One straightforward way would be the following:

```
output = []
for element in doubleList:
    if element[3] in ListNum:
        output.append(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension to achieve that,  I would code it like this:

```
ans = [l for l in doubleList if l[-1] in ListNum]
```

the -1 index is getting the last element of each list from doubleList, and then checking if it is contained inside ListNum.

BTW, if the length of ListNum is big it would be pretty inefficient. What you can do is build a set, in order to make the "in" calls in constant time. In python it is straightforward: `ListNumSet = set(ListNum)`, keep in mind it removes duplicates and do not support indexing.